# Using tables as data column types in different flavours of SQL?

Tags: sql

In PostgreSQL this is allowed:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1(
    a int
);

CREATE TABLE test2
(
  a test1
);
```

But it's not allowed in MySQL. Is there any other syntax for this in MySQL or is it completely missing.

Do other SQL flavours (MariaDB, SQLServer, Oracle) support this?

Note:  I am not about using db objects created via `CREATE TYPE`.

Comment: I think this is unique to Postgres.

Comment: "*I am not about using db objects created via CREATE TYPE"* - well, actually you do. Every `create table` also creates a TYPE with the same name as the table. That's why you can use the table name as a column type

Comment: This is not standard ansi sql, different databases might implement their own way of working, eg SQL Server has a *table type*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment posted by @a_horse_with_no_name answers the question.

For every `CREATE TABLE` statement in Postgres, a corresponding `TYPE` is created automatically by the db engine.

This type can now used as a column type.

MySQL and MariaDB don't have user-defined types.

For Oracle DBMS and SQL Server, the same can be achieved by explicitly creating a Type.